# Show content type teaser only if posts available for the content type

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I'm displaying a content type teaser view on the front page using Twig Tweak. But I want to show it only if there are posts available. Something like

```
{% if content type has posts %}
  <h1>Upcoming Events</h1>
  {{ drupal_view('home_upcoming_event_teaser') }}
{% endif %}
```

How can I achieve this in a Twig Template?

Comment: Use a View for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drupal_view_result` to check if your view has result:

From [Cheat sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x)

> {# This might be useful to check if a view returns nothing. #}
>
> View results:
>
> {{ drupal_view_result('who_s_new', 'block_1') }}

Your code will be something like:

```
{% if drupal_view_result('home_upcoming_event_teaser') is not empty %}
  <h1>Upcoming Events</h1>
  {{ drupal_view('home_upcoming_event_teaser') }}
{% endif %}
```